# iOS cpu usage for each process using sysctl()?

Tags: objective-c, ios, sysctl

**Is there a way to get cpu usage for each process using sysctl() ?**

I'm trying to find a way to detect the launch of a specific application. It seems there's no way to get foreground running app information. So I guess if I can monitor cpu usage for that specific app I can monitor the cpu usage changes and roughly assume when the app launches. Is this possible at all?

**I'm not planning to publish this app to apple appstore.**

This is only a research. So if there is ANY way to do this I'm glad to know.

Answer (score 6):

Go through the following process 1. Import Following Files

```
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <mach/mach.h>
#include <mach/processor_info.h>
#include <mach/mach_host.h>
```

2. Add ivars

```
processor_info_array_t cpuInfo, prevCpuInfo;
mach_msg_type_number_t numCpuInfo, numPrevCpuInfo;
unsigned numCPUs;
NSTimer *updateTimer;
NSLock *CPUUsageLock;
```

3.IN .m file

```
-(void)voidDidLoad
{
int mib[2U] = { CTL_HW, HW_NCPU };
size_t sizeOfNumCPUs = sizeof(numCPUs);
int status = sysctl(mib, 2U, &numCPUs, &sizeOfNumCPUs, NULL, 0U);
if(status)
    numCPUs = 1;

CPUUsageLock = [[NSLock alloc] init];

updateTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3
                                                target:self
                                              selector:@selector(updateInfo:)
                                              userInfo:nil
                                               repeats:YES] retain];    
}
- (void)updateInfo:(NSTimer *)timer
{
natural_t numCPUsU = 0U;
kern_return_t err = host_processor_info(mach_host_self(), PROCESSOR_CPU_LOAD_INFO, &numCPUsU, &cpuInfo, &numCpuInfo);
if(err == KERN_SUCCESS) {
    [CPUUsageLock lock];

    for(unsigned i = 0U; i < numCPUs; ++i) {
        float inUse, total;
        if(prevCpuInfo) {
            inUse = (
                     (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER]   - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER])
                     + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM])
                     + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE]   - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE])
                     );
            total = inUse + (cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE] - prevCpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE]);
        } else {
            inUse = cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_USER] + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_SYSTEM] + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_NICE];
            total = inUse + cpuInfo[(CPU_STATE_MAX * i) + CPU_STATE_IDLE];
        }

        NSLog(@"Core: %u Usage: %f",i,inUse / total);
    }
    [CPUUsageLock unlock];

    if(prevCpuInfo) {
        size_t prevCpuInfoSize = sizeof(integer_t) * numPrevCpuInfo;
        vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(), (vm_address_t)prevCpuInfo, prevCpuInfoSize);
    }

    prevCpuInfo = cpuInfo;
    numPrevCpuInfo = numCpuInfo;

    cpuInfo = NULL;
    numCpuInfo = 0U;
} else {
    NSLog(@"Error!");
    [NSApp terminate:nil];
}
```

}

Comment: Hi Ankit, thank you verymuch for the answer. But I still couldn't figure out a way to get cpu usage by process id. if you have a sample code snippet it would be extremely helpful. thank you!

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the answer. However , does this code log cpu usage for each process? I would like to know the cpu usage for 'Youtube' applicaiton or 'Camera' application by passing their PIDs to a function. If you can give me a clue it's highly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for answer. How to get total idle cpu time? (NOT for each process).